# Issues submitting a job on an SGE cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, sungridengine

I am trying to submit a simple "hello world" to test a gridengine (I used it before with no problems)

The problem is that my job is waiting in the queue forever

The qhost command shows a wired state of the compute nodes

```
HOSTNAME                ARCH         NCPU  LOAD  MEMTOT  MEMUSE  SWAPTO  SWAPUS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
global                  -               -     -       -       -       -       -
compute001              lx26-amd64      4     -   31.4G       -     0.0       -
compute002              lx26-amd64      4     -   31.4G       -     0.0       -
compute003              lx26-amd64      4     -   31.4G       -     0.0       -
compute004              lx26-amd64      4     -   31.4G       -     0.0       -
compute005              lx26-amd64      4     -   31.4G       -     0.0       -
compute006              lx26-amd64      4     -   31.4G       -     0.0       -
compute007              lx26-amd64      4     -   31.4G       -     0.0       -
compute008              lx26-amd64      4     -   31.4G       -     0.0       -
compute009              lx26-amd64      4     -   31.4G       -     0.0       -
compute010              lx26-amd64      4     -   31.4G       -     0.0       -
compute011              lx26-amd64      4     -   31.4G       -     0.0
```

In normal times even when the compute nodes are not used I used to have some information on the `load` and `memuse` columns

I am not an SGE persons but I am familiar with all the commands, any help would be much appreciated

the `qstat -f` command shows all my nodes in `au` state. I've been reading a lot about it and I understood its an alarm state (overloaded ?)

the only heavy activity I had on the head node was a script downloading 19T of data, could the headnode be the problem and not the compute nodes ?

Comment: Is sge_execd running on your nodes? If so `qhost` should report stats for load, memuse and swapus.

Comment: Yes sge_execd is running on the exec nodes :/

Comment: I am trying to restart sge_execd though but I am having this error
root@compute010:/home/ubuntu# /usr/lib/gridengine/sge_execd
error: can't find connection
error: can't get configuration from qmaster -- backgrounding

Comment: My usual fix for this is: (1) `qstat -f` to make sure which nodes are affected i.e. in abnormal state, (2) `qmod -c '*'` to clear configuration of any issue and check if that solves it. If not, (3) on each compute node `skill sge_execd` then restart `/etc/init.d/sge_execd start` or equivalent for systemd.

Comment: Tried all this with no success :/

the last command gives me error: can't find connection
error: can't get configuration from qmaster -- backgrounding

Comment: Are all your $SGE_* environment variables configured properly both on the master and worker nodes?

Comment: I assume that all this was working previously, and that you did not change config? If so, then I would try and diagnose from low-level to higher level issues. Can you ping the sge master node from the compute node? If qmaster deamon running properly on sge master node (maybe stop/start it). If all else fails, just reboot qmaster and compute nodes. Sometimes that is the easiest solution for issues such as this.